# CSS files not found in _catalogs/theme/themed/... folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

Good day,

We have created a page that's inside a Team Site site collection with publishing features enabled. We use a custom master page and a custom pagelayout.

Now when we try to add a Summary Links web part to that page, we noticed that it's trying and failing to retrieve the following css:

- /_catalogs/theme/Themed/7FA80357/pagelayouts15-ACE7C7F2.themedcss?ctag=1
- /_catalogs/theme/Themed/7FA80357/controls15-51FFDD78.themedcss?ctag=1

This results in the web part styling failing.

However, when we create a page with the Summary Links web part under a Publishing Portal site collection, it searches for the CSS files as such:

- /Style%20Library/en-US/Themable/Core%20Styles/pagelayouts15.css
- /Style%20Library/en-US/Themable/Core%20Styles/controls15.css

They are then found and the web part is rendered correctly.

What is going on? Why has it changed the location of where to find the CSS files in the first case? I hope you can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically when you **activate a custom theme** on a site, what will happen is a bunch of files from the file system will be rendered with custom colors and images and placed under `_catalogs\theme\Themed\<some-id>`

This is done for you under the hood through the use of instruction replacement, e.g.

```
/* [ReplaceFont(themeFont:"heading")] */ font-family:"Segoe UI Semilight","Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"StrongBodyText")] */ color:#262626;
```

What you need to worry about is `inheritance`, for example, activating a theme on the root site of your site collection and then setting all your subsites to use that theme as well, otherwise those sites will use the default theme instead.

Additionally, team sites and publishing sites use different styles and master pages, so it's not unusual to see different CSS files being referenced.